# ion-item reduce width of end slot

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to make the end slot of my list item take up less width so I can make the name in the first slot longer.

Currently it takes up around 50% of the width and is wasting space.

[image]

```
<ion-list *ngIf="!isLoading">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let trail of trails" #defectReport (click)="onViewTrailDetails(trail)">

    <fa-icon class="icon icon-center status-open-icon" *ngIf="trail.status === trailStatus.Open" slot="start" [icon]="['fas', 'check-circle']" size="2x"></fa-icon>
    <fa-icon class="icon icon-center status-closed-icon" *ngIf="trail.status === trailStatus.Closed" slot="start" [icon]="['fas', 'times-circle']" size="2x"></fa-icon>
    <fa-icon class="icon icon-center status-new-icon" *ngIf="trail.status === trailStatus.New" slot="start" [icon]="['fas', 'burn']" size="2x"></fa-icon>
    <fa-icon class="icon icon-center status-under-construction-icon" *ngIf="trail.status === trailStatus.UnderConstruction" slot="start" [icon]="['fas', 'exclamation-triangle']" size="2x"></fa-icon>

    <ion-label class="first-item-label">
      <span><h2 class="heading">{{trail.name}}</h2></span>
      <p class="label-text">{{trail.status}}</p>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-label slot="end" class="second-item-label">
      <p class="sub-heading">{{trail.statusNotes}}</p>
      <p class="label-text-small">{{trail.lastUpdated | timeAgo}}</p>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using ion-note.  It caused some formatting issues but resolved my problem.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/note

```
    <ion-note slot="end" class="second-item-label" [ngClass]="{'margin-top-auto': !trail.statusNotes}">
      <p class="sub-heading">{{trail.statusNotes}}</p>
      <p class="label-text-small">{{trail.lastUpdated | timeAgo}}</p>
    </ion-note>
```

Comment: It works, but `ion-note` styles are different from `ion-label` styles. You may need to fix your styles inline if you want to have the same result as a smaller `ion-label`.

Answer (score 1):

`ion-item` is a `flex` container and `ion-label` has the style `flex-grow: 1`.

What I did is setting the first to `flex-grow: 2`, resulting in 2/3, 1/3 responsive proportions for labels.

In your case just add this to the CSS:

```css
.first-item-label {
    flex-grow: 2;
}
```

If you want the last label to have a fixed width, do this instead:

```css
.second-item-label {
    flex: 0 0 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the following. Just change / reset the `flex` style of the label element, since it's a flex layout.

```css
ion-label[slot='end'] {
  flex: unset;
  text-align: end;
}
```

The property `text-align: end` is optional and has nothing to do with the question. But in my opinion the right slot of an item should be right aligned. Especially input field.

You could use every element you want. But `ion-label` has some predefined styles which harmonize with the framework. And `ion-note` changes e.g. the font-size (in md style).

Update: This will be fixed in upcoming Ionic version (maybe Ionic 6). With this change `flex: 1` is not longer set on `slot="end"`.